# Program hangs due to too many regex-based replacements

Tags: regex, string, replace

In my input file, I need to do lots of string-manipulations (find/replaces) using Regex depending on various conditions. Like, if the content's one block meets the condition, I need to go to previous block and do replacement in that block.

For this reason, I am splitting the content to many substrings, so that I can move back to previous block (here, previous substring); and do the REGEX replacement.
But the Program hangs in the middle if the File content is more(or may be, no. of substrings exceeds).

Here is the code snippet.

```
string content = string.Empty;
string target_content = string.Empty;
string[] active_doc_nos;
byte[] content_bytes;
FileInfo input_fileinfo = new FileInfo(input_file);
long file_length = input_fileinfo.Length;
using (FileStream fs_read = new FileStream(input_file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    content_bytes = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(file_length)];
    fs_read.Read(content_bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file_length));
    fs_read.Close();
}
content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(content_bytes);
if (Regex.IsMatch(content, "<\\?CLG.MDFO ([^>]*) LEVEL=\"STRUCTURE\""))
{
    #region Logic-1: TWO PAIRS of MDFO-MDFC-s one pair following the other
    content = Regex.Replace(content, "(<\\?CLG.MDFO)([^>]*)(LEVEL=\"STRUCTURE\")", "<MDFO_VALIDATOR>$1$2$3");
    string[] MDFO_Lines = Regex.Split(content, "<MDFO_VALIDATOR>");
    active_doc_nos = new string[MDFO_Lines.GetLength(0)];
    active_doc_nos[0] = Regex.Match(MDFO_Lines[0], "ACTIVE DOC=\"([^>]*)\"\\s+").ToString();
for (int i = 1; i < MDFO_Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    active_doc_nos[i] = Regex.Match(MDFO_Lines[i], "ACTIVE DOC=\"([^>]*)\"\\s+").ToString();
    if (Regex.IsMatch(MDFO_Lines[i - 1], "(<\\?CLG.MDFC)([^>]*)(\\?>)(<\\S*\\s*\\S*>)*$"))
    {
        MDFO_Lines[i - 1] = Regex.Replace(MDFO_Lines[i - 1], "(<\\?CLG.MDFC)([^>]*)(\\?>)(<\\S*\\s*\\S*>)*$", "<?no_smark?>$1$2$3$4");
        if (Regex.IsMatch(MDFO_Lines[i - 1], "^<\\?CLG.MDFO ([^>]*) ACTION=\"DELETED\""))
        {
            MDFO_Lines[i - 1] = Regex.Replace(MDFO_Lines[i - 1], "^<\\?CLG.MDFO ([^>]*) ACTION=\"DELETED\"", "<?no_bmark?><?CLG.MDFO $1 ACTION=\"DELETED\"");
        }
        if (active_doc_nos[i] == active_doc_nos[i - 1])
        {
            MDFO_Lines[i] = Regex.Replace(MDFO_Lines[i], "^<\\?CLG.MDFO ([^>]*) " + active_doc_nos[i], "<?no_smark?><?CLG.MDFO $1 " + active_doc_nos[i]);
        }
    }
}
foreach (string str_piece in MDFO_Lines)
{
   target_content += str_piece;
}
byte[] target_bytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(target_content);
using (FileStream fs_write = new FileStream(input_file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fs_write.Write(target_bytes, 0, target_bytes.Length);
    fs_write.Close();
}
```

Do I have any other option to achieve this task??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your data, but I have a suspicion that this part of some of your regexes may be the culprit:

```
(<\\S*\\s*\\S*>)*
```

Because `\S` can also match `<` and `>`, because everything is optional, and because you've got nested quantifiers, it's possible that this part of the regex leads to catastrophic backtracking.

What happens if you replace these parts with `(?>(<\\S*\\s*\\S*>))*`?